# Testing asynchronous Web Service calls in Play Framework 2.0

Tags: java, testing, asynchronous, junit, playframework-2.0

I have a number of low-level methods in my play! 2.0 application (Java) that are calling an external Web Service (Neo4j via REST, to be specific). Each of them returns a `Promise<WS.Response>`. To test these methods I am currently installing a `Callback<WS.Response>` on their return values via `onRedeem`. The `Callback`s contain the assertions to perform on individual `WS.Response`s. Each test relies on some specific fixtures that I am installing/removing via `setUpClass` and `tearDownClass`, respectively.

The problem that I am facing is that due to my test code being fully asynchronous, the tear-down logic ends up getting called **before** all of the `Callback`s have had a chance to run. As a result, not all fixtures are being removed, and the database is left in a state that is different from the state it was in before running the tests.

One way to fix this problem would be to call `get()` with some arbitrary timeout on the `Promise` objects returned by the functions that are being tested, but that solution seems fairly brittle and unreliable to me. (What if, for some reason not under my application's control, the Web Service calls do not complete within the timeout? In that case, my tests would fail or error out even though my code is actually correct.)

**So my question is**: Is there a way of testing code that calls external Web Services that is non-blocking and still ensures database consistency? And if there isn't, which of the two approaches outlined above is the "canonical"/accepted way of testing this kind of code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What if, for some reason not under my application's control, the Web Service calls do not complete within the timeout?

That is a problem for *any* test that calls external web services, whether asynchronous or not. That is why you should mock out your web service calls in some way, either using a fake web service or a fake implementation of the code that accesses the web service.

You can use e.g. Betamax for that.

I have written testing code for asynchronous code before and I believe your "brittle" approach is actually the right one.